# Weird bug in MPLAB X IDE

Tags: pic, assembly, mplabx

When using the RTCC module in the PIC24F, we need to use the secondary oscillator (by setting bit #2 of OSCCONL register) and disable the write lock on the RTCC registers. Now the write lock can be done by using the following pattern according the application note:

```
MOV #NVMKEY, W1 ;move the address of NVMKEY into W1
MOV.b #0x55, W2
MOV.b #0xAA, W3
MOV.b W2, [W1] ;start 55/AA sequence
MOV.b W3, [W1]
BSET RCFGCAL, #13 ;set the RTCWREN bit
```

Now this pattern does not work. And the cause can be found at the disassebly of these instruction used in C code (asm volatile):

```
!void enable_RTCWREN()
!{
0x33A: LNK #0x0
!    asm volatile ("MOV   #NVMKEY, W1");
0x33C: MOV #0x766, W1
!    asm volatile ("MOV.b #0x55, W2");
0x33E: MOV.B #0x55, W2
!    asm volatile ("MOV.b #0xAA, W3");
0x340: MOV.B #0xAA, W3
!    asm volatile ("MOV.b W2, [W1]");
0x342: MOV.B W2, [W1]
!    asm volatile ("MOV.b W3, [W1]");
0x344: MOV.B W3, [W1]
!    asm volatile ("BSET RCFGCAL, #13");
0x346: BSET 0x627, #5
!}
0x348: ULNK
0x34A: RETURN
```

WHY DOES MPLAB X IDE COMPILE THE CONSTANT #13 AS #5! Therefore the RTCC write lock is not disabled and the module won't start at all!!

Comment: I bet that RCFGCAL is a 16 bit register which address is 0x626. So setting the 13th bit is the same thing as setting the 5th (5=13-8) but at address 0x627.

Comment: That's because memory is byte addressed and in a RISC architecture you can usually operate directly on just a byte

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer! I understood why, but checkout my next next question, apparently there are two write lock sequences.